# Support AppleScript for entities that are not actual objects

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I'm trying to implement AppleScript support in an OS X app. In the Cocoa Scripting documentation they keep mentioning that it is possible to have scriptable AppleScript entities that are not represented by real instances in the app e.g. a text editing app, that allows accessing "words" and "characters" via AppleScript, but does not actually have a Word or Character class (just a string to store the text).

> Sometimes an application's object model provides scripting access to
>   objects at a level of granularity that would be impractical to
>   implement with individual objects. For example, an AppleScript script
>   can ask for the characters of a text document, but it would be quite
>   expensive for an application to represent each character as an object.
>   The `NSTextStorage` class handles this case with a special accessor
>   method, `characters`.

I don't understand how I can achieve the same thing in a very similar case. What does "a special accessor method" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not the accessor method itself that’s special so much as its return value.  Ultimately, any scriptable “object” in your application must be backed by an Objective-C object -- KVC has to have something to work with -- but it can be an object that’s only created when needed by scripting.  For example, “characters” of text could be handled by making `characters` return an NSArray subclass that implements `-objectAtIndex:` to make “character” objects on demand.  Alternatively, you could implement `countOfCharacters` and `objectInCharactersAtIndex:`, similarly returning on-demand “character” objects.  (See Cocoa Scripting Guide, under “Maintain KVC Compliance”.)